How to disable unknown tracker alerts for specific trusted Airtags
Is there a way to mark specific Airtags, that belong to other people, as trusted so your phone never generates stalker alerts for them?
This is needed for example if you put airtags in your car, or in your childrens' bags, and they are all attached to one icloud account.   Everyone in the family except the owner gets constant useless stalker warnings.   You can turn off warnings entirely but that's not desireable.   You want to say "I trust this airtag even though I don't own it" so your own phone stops notifying it.  Can you?
